# NavigationView custom menu item

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a Drawer with a header and some menu items in it. I have created the header as a separate layout, and put it into the NavigationView like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="312dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">
```

The header appears correctly. The problem is that the menu is not customizable, by default. Therefore, I put the `app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_menu_item"` attribute for each item in the menu, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group>
    <item android:id="@+id/navDocumentScanItem"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_menu_item"
        android:title="@null"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/navReportItem"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_menu_item"
        android:title="@null"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/navHallOfFameItem"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_menu_item"
        android:title="@null"/>
</group>
```

In my nav_menu_item I have the layout that I want to use for each item in my drawer menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navItem"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/navItemIcon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    tools:src="@drawable/nav_icon_qr_scan"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/navItemText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/navItemIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/menu_item_text_style"
    tools:text="Document Scanning"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This appears reasonably well (if I hardcode it), but the problem is that I can't access the views in this custom layout. How do I get a handle of the "navItemIcon" and "navItemText" so that I can set the icon and text programatically, depending on which item position is for that particular item? I need to modify these when the activity starts, so that the correct text and icon sources are being set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it - I used the ViewTreeObserver to update the items programmatically. I will leave the solution here as it might help someone.

```
//handle the navigation drawer item
    val navViewTreeObserver = navView.viewTreeObserver
    navViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            navView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            val menu = navView.menu
            //get the menu items of the navigation view
            for (i in 0 until menu.size()){
                val menuItem = menu.getItem(i)
                //get the relevant views that we want to change programmatically
                val menuItemText = menuItem.actionView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.navItemText)
                val menuItemIcon = menuItem.actionView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.navItemIcon)
                //change the menu item's text and icon depending on the position in the drawer
                when (i){
                    0 -> {
                        menuItemText.text = "Document Scan"
                        menuItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nav_icon_qr_scan)
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        menuItemText.text = "Activity Reports"
                        menuItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nav_icon_report_inactive)
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        menuItemText.text = "Hall of fame"
                        menuItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nav_icon_hall_of_fame_inactive)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```